# Composer fails to download Google Text-To-Speech library

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, composer-php, google-text-to-speech

I am trying to import Google's Text-To-Speech library

`composer require google/cloud-text-to-speech`

But I get this error

```
Using version ^0.4.4 for google/cloud-text-to-speech
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for google/cloud-text-to-speech ^0.4.4 -> satisfiable by google/cloud-text-to-speech[v0.4.4].
    - Conclusion: don't install google/gax 0.37.0
    - google/cloud-text-to-speech v0.4.4 requires google/gax ^1.0 -> satisfiable by google/gax[1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3].
    - Can only install one of: google/gax[1.0.0, 0.37.0].
    - Can only install one of: google/gax[1.0.1, 0.37.0].
    - Can only install one of: google/gax[1.0.2, 0.37.0].
    - Can only install one of: google/gax[1.0.3, 0.37.0].
    - Installation request for google/gax (locked at 0.37.0) -> satisfiable by google/gax[0.37.0].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

How can I fix this? Is there any available libraries to download without using Composer?

Comment: Please provide your composer.json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like either you or another dependency in your project also requires `google/gax`, but in an older version. You can find out why `google/gax` is locked at version 0.37.0 using the why command:

```sh
composer why google/gax
```

This should tell you wether it's installed as a root dependency, meaning you explicitly installed it or which other dependency requires it.

Then you have to find out whether there is a newer version of that dependency, so you can upgrade that dependency to be able to use a newer version of `google/gax`. If you determine updating it is safe just add both extensions to the require command or update the dependency first and then try requiring `google/cloud-text-to-speech` again.

Composer also provides a way to automatically update all dependencies for you, but this obviously risks introducing breaking changes from the updates, so use this with proper care:

```
--update-with-dependencies      Allows inherited dependencies to be updated, except those that are root requirements.
--update-with-all-dependencies  Allows all inherited dependencies to be updated, including those that are root requirements.
```

So running:

```sh
composer require --update-with-all-dependencies google/cloud-text-to-speech
```

should update your application in a way that it supports the required version of `google/gax` in order to install `google/cloud-text-to-speech`. This will likely result in other dependencies being updated and you can check the output to see which ones were affected.